# In Area51, the markdown editing help is borked

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, area-51

Just look at this:
[image]
Why is there no alien background? And why is there no header? The page is just empty, with a color background and the info. Please add the fancy aliens back. What did they do to offend you? They are left out of everything!

Comment: Whoever who closed voted this, why is there the area51 tag?

Comment: are you serious?

Comment: @santiago Yes I am

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the content of that page

Comment: There's no background

Comment: that's good, less noise.... content is far more important than window dressing fluffiness

Comment: It doesn't belong on Area 51 Discussions, indeed. That is to discuss site proposals, not Area 51 itself. Area 51 is a special case that way. Voting to leave open.

Comment: *What* is wrong? You stated "Just look at this:" ok I did, I see, some stuff. Then you stated "Please add the fancy aliens back. What did they do to offend you? They are left out of everything!". What? What is wrong? A funny line is fine, but only after you've explained what's wrong and not left people guessing (which is likely why the downvotes). bug reports are tracked and viewed by Stack staff, so it's common decency to provide at least a basic report explaining what you feel is wrong, so their time is not wasted.

Comment: Nothing is "borked". You can make this more constructive by actually suggesting some specific redesign, even with a mockup, not just say "it's borked, fix it"

Comment: @ShadowWizard considering the fact that [no page actually links to that page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260964/260841)... that'd just be a waste of time!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ *facepalm* - didn't even occur to me to check!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe, just maybe... that's because you **can't access** http://area51.stackexchange.com/editing-help without *directly typing* that into the address bar. No page on Area51 links to that link:

- No link from creating an example question
- No link from proposing a site

And that's just about everywhere you'll find somewhere you can input text on http://area51.stackexchange.com.

**However**, there are links to the editing-help on http://***discuss***.area51.stackexchange.com. See [Area 51 **Discussion Zone** editing help](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) -- everything's there, like it should.

There's no point fixing something that hasn't explicitly been linked to *anywhere* on the site.

Comment: +1 Upon checking the content of the Area 51 Discussion Zone editing help  page, it seems like this is a new page for editing help. I wonder if there is any need of the old one. May be 301 redirect will take care of it as I don;t find any references in Google search except this post that's because now it got indexed.

Comment: @HackerKarma Area 51 and Area 51 Discuss are not the same site.

Comment: @AnnaLear I did not know that... I concentrated more on "Area 51" word... Could you please tell where is editing help section for Area 51?